# A basic question on interpreting a battery ratings

Tags: batteries

A phone battery has the following ratings on its plate:
[image]

It says 3.8V 7.22Wh. Does that mean the battery can provide 1.9A constant current to a 1 Ohm load for an hour with a little battery voltage change? This 1.9A has nothing to do with how much the battery sources current to the phone in real correct? I cannot find any info about [this](https://support.sprint.com/global/pdf/user_guides/samsung/galaxy_s_4/galaxy_s_4_by_samsung_ug.pdf) phone's max current rating so it is something mystery for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.8 V and 7.22 Wh does not tell you the max continuous current that you can draw out of it. There is another parameter called "C - rating" which gives you the max continuous current. This is how it works:

A 1000 mAh battery rated for 5 C will be able to give you 1000 mA X 5 = 5 A of continuous current.

In your case, the battery can be considered as 1900 mAh (7.22/3.8 mAh).

A lot of times, battery capacity is mentioned at 1C which means you should be able to draw a max of 1900 mA = 1.9 A continuously and it will discharge in 1 hour.

Li-po batteries will typically mention C rating explicitly:

[image: lipo]

Comment: But it will discharge in one hour on what load? 1 Ohm?

Comment: If it has to draw 1.9 A, then R = 3.8 V /1.9 A = 2 ohms.

Comment: If you out 1 ohm, it will want to draw 3.8 A which is more than max current that it can supply.

Comment: And if the load was 4 Ohm can we say the duration increases to two hours?

Comment: Yes. At 4 ohms, duration increases to 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it is unrelated. It only says it has 7.22 Wh, and delivers 3.8V (at least at start).

The maximum current is a separate value which is not mentioned. Assume it would be 1.9 A, than indeed, 1.9 A * 3.8 V = 7.22 W, for one hour.

However, chances are big the maximum current is lower, and therefore the battery lasts longer.

Comment: But what is the load in your calculation 1 Ohm? For one hour the current passes through what load?

Comment: @atmnt forgot ohm's law ?

Comment: Sorry u re right I was a bit confused